# Run gitlab-ci.yml only when merge request to master made

Tags: node.js, heroku, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am currently having my project in *GitLab* and *Heroku*. What I wanna do is as soon as I ask for merge request with my feature branch (let's call it `crud-on-spaghetti`), I want to automatically run the tests on this branch (`npm test` basically, using Mocha/Chai), and after they succeed, merge this `crud-on-spaghetti` with `master`, commit it and push it to `origin/master` (which is remote on GitLab) and after `git push heroku master` (basically, push it to the master branch in Heroku, where my app is stored). I have read several articles on GitLab CI and I think this is more suitable for me (rather than Heroku CI, because I do not have DEV and PROD instances).

So, as of now, I do this manually. And this is my `.gitlab-ci.yml` file now (which is not committed/pushed yet):

```
stages:
  - test
  - deploy

test_for_illegal_bugs:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm test

deploy_to_dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - origin master
  script:
    - git commit
    - git push origin master
    - git pull heroku master --rebase
    - git push heroku master
```

Hence, my questions is: What do I exactly need to write in `.gitlab-ci.yml` in order to automate all these "manipulations" (above)?

PS. And another (theoretical) follow-up question: how is GitLab-CI Runner triggered? For instance, if I want it to trigger upon merge request with master, do I do that using `only: ...` in `.gitlab-ci.yml`?

Comment: Remove `origin` from the `only:` part.

Comment: The test stage is triggered by every commit on every branch. To restrict it to merge requests, add `only: merge_requests` to the stage.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
only:
  - master
```

`origin` is just a name for a remote. `master` is the name of the branch.

The runner is triggered by GitLab-CI the moment that a commit is pushed to the repository, so alas not upon merge request.

You can use a `trigger` to trigger a pipeline and then call that trigger from a merge request event in `integrations`.

Comment: Here what I receive after pushing the changes http://prntscr.com/fblm8h

Comment: @alwaysone You can check the output of that stage on GitLab. Does your runner have all the tools it needs, like node / npm ?

Comment: Yep, I forgot ```image: node:latest```. However, I cannot push into Heroku as I need to define Heroku's API key. How do I do that? Through ```dpl``` tool?

Comment: Little update to my latest comment: defined the Heroku API key through the VSC (Gitlab) as a `config var`

Answer (score 26):

As of 2023 the keywords `only` and `except` have been deprecated in favor of `rules` ([see docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules)).

### In newer versions

Using `rules:` to restrict the execution of a job to a merge request to the target branch:

```
  rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
```

### For older versions

**Restrict stages to Merge Requests:**

To have your `test` stage only being executed when a Merge Request (MR) is opened, use:

```
   only:
     - merge_requests
```

According to the [Gitlab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/merge_request_pipelines/index.html#excluding-certain-branches), you can further restrict this to only being executed for MRs with a certain target branch, e.g. only MRs for `master`

```
   only:
     - merge_requests
   except:
     variables:
       - $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME != "master"
```

This adds an exception for all target branches that are not `master`.

**Restrict stages to Branches:**

As already mentioned by @marcolz, this is achieved by

```
   only:
     - master
```

to only execute the stage for pushes to the master branch.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think that the rule one should use is to detect a "result merge event":

```
($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_EVENT_TYPE   == "merged_result") &&
 ($CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH)
```

see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merged_results_pipelines.html

otherwise, the stage might run regardless if merge request was approved or not and finished successfully.